# Opening/reading .dat file in Fortran77

Tags: file, file-io, fortran, fortran77

I'm trying to read through a set of points in a .dat file and to run the points through an algorithm in my .f file. I've been working with the OPEN statement:

```
OPEN(UNIT=1,FILE='POINTS.DAT',FORM='UNFORMATTED')
```

and for a starter, have been trying to print out the values in the .dat - not working.

```
PRINT *, 1

PRINT *, POINTS.DAT

PRINT *, 'POINTS.DAT'
```

Should I ditch trying to print out the values? How should I be indexing the values in the .dat? Should I do a DO loop and have it loop n times through my the number of data points in my file? How do I call those values?

Comment: what does your .dat file look like? did you create it?

Comment: you should first find some material to introduce the basics of programming/fortran to you.  Also, why do you want/need to read that file, why with fortran, do you have any programming experience?

Answer (score 7):

After the open you have to read the values from the file.  You can't print them by using the file name in a print statement.   If you are correct that is is a binary / unformatted file, you use a read without a format: `read (1) item`.   You can either use a do loop and read one item at a time or read all the items into an array.   If the file was written with another Fortran program, you should use the same method (single item or array) as was used for writing because the file will be record based.  If the file was written with another language, add *access='stream'* to your open statement to inform Fortran that it doesn't have the record structure normally used by Fortran.

Basic structure 1:

```
real :: item  ! or whatever type
open (unit=1, ...
ReadLoop: do
  read (1, end=99) item
  process item...
end do ReadLoop
99 continue
```

Basic structure 2:

```
real, dimension (NUMBER) :: array
open (unit=1,..
read (1) array
process array...
```

This is basic Fortran ... you will probably make faster progress if you find a book to learn from.  I like *Fortran 90/95 Explained* by Metcalf and Reid.

Comment: Just as a side-note the most recent revision of the Metcalf book is called "Modern Fortran Explained".

Comment: @haraldkl - I'm dying to know what the next one will be called, now that they've changed the title from "fortran version explained" to "modern fortran explained" .... "Postmodern ..."?

Comment: @haraldkl, thanks for the update on the Metcalf book.  Idigas, yes that title is a potential trap -- how will the book read in the era of Fortran 2050 ?! -- it reminds me of the outdated physics textbooks from the 1950s called "Modern Physics".